# Detecting a stale Mutex

Tags: delphi, multithreading, debugging, delphi-2010

Is there any technique or tool available to detect this kind of a deadlock during runtime?

picture this in a worker thread (one of several, normally 4-6)

```
try
   WaitForSingleObject(myMutex);
   DoSTuffThatMightCauseAnException;
except
   ReleaseMutex(myMutex);
end;
```

or more generally is there a design-pattern to avoid these kind of bugs?

I coded the above code in the little hous after a longer hacking run

Comment: @allenporter: The mutex is only released when an exception occurs, so a normal execution leads to the mutex not being released

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A better coding style is to use try/finally instead of try/except for the mutex release (or any other kind of resource release, for that matter), ie:

```
try
  WaitForSingleObject(myMutex); 
  try 
    DoSTuffThatMightCauseAnException; 
  finally
    ReleaseMutex(myMutex); 
  end; 
except
  ...
end;
```